# Can anyone suggest a similar 3D cube flipping image banner in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have this incredible website reference http://rdcm.com/en/. I would like to to know if similar jquery library exist which is full width and auto fits to the height. i have tried to adapt and modify libraries like cudeslider jquery but i face resolution issue especially retina ready mac book pro etc and also handheld and tablet devices although not my primary concerns for these devices but desktop and laptops are my target devices.